# AMD A8 7680 Drivers Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: radeon, amd-graphics, amd-processor, amdgpu, amdgpu-pro

The amdgpu driver should is pre-installed in Linux 16.04. The kernel module is amdgpu, but after the system is up and running, there is no no driver in use. I tried to istall mmdgpu-pro but it didn't work. So I only get the support for 1024x768 given by bios as I had to use nomodeset in the grub configuration. Is there any way to get support to AMD A8 7680 APU with R7 gpu inside?

Comment: How do you know amdgpu is not in use? What is "mmdgpu-pro"? Why do you use nomodeset?

Comment: Sorry for the typo: "mmdgpu-pro" is "amdgpu-pro" driver. The grub option "nomodeset" is required in order to avoid the issue of blank/pink screen at the boot time.  Once the system is up and running, from terminal I checked the video driver in use by using the command  lshw -c video  but there is no  "driver=" at "configuration:" entry. Then I also used  lspci -nnk | grep -i vga -A3  and indeed amdgpu was listed in "Kernel modules:"  but no entry for "Kernel driver in use:".

Answer (score 0):

Been dealing with a blank screen right after boot for days (different versions of Ubuntu-Kubuntu-LinuxMint-CentOS (both 32 and 64 bits), until I read a post on reddit and passed this kernel parameter at boot time (instead of nomodeset):

amdgpu.dc=0

My box is an A8-7680 with R7 (Wani), MSI A68HM-E33V2. Worked for me, hope it works for you!